# The [dvr] is too grainy. Can't we get better [cctv]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[dvr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dvr)(59 questions) and [cctv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cctv)(47 questions, some overlap), with many of them about setting up and installing DVRs and cameras (not on-topic at all).

The few on-topic questions are using it as a meta tag. Short burn for both.

Comment: but according to a-ha... "the sun always shines on (cc)tv"? :p

Comment: Hmm, we have 58 users that added these tags to their Favorite Tags section in their profile.  And 1 that forgot to add them to his Ignored Tags section.  You can easily fix that.

Comment: Is kinda backwards to have a tag in your favorites and not having more than 1 answer in the entire tag... heck, both tags have a 60% unanswered rate. SO in general sits at 29%. Not even Software recommendations has a higher unanswered rate which is 46%. And nobody can claim that those tags are unpopular, as they have 1 user per 2 questions...